# Rebasing multiple branches simulteniously

Tags: git, rebase

First : In my case I am the only developer and pull, merge, etc.conflicts with other developers are not an issue at the moment.

I have a branch three that looks something like that. I have one master branch and multiple testing branches that are children of the master branch. However some of the changes I make need to be applied at the master branch and then all other branches are rebased with it so to have the same features/bugs as the master variant.

My usual workflow in this case is :

1. I commit changes to the master

   ```
   git commit -as
   ```
2. Then I have to go through all the other branches and rebase them with master.

   ```
   git checkout test_1
   git rebase master
   git checkout test_2
   git rebase master
   git checkout test_3
   git rebase master
   git checkout test_4
   git rebase master
   ...
   ```

Is there a way to automate that. I am on `ubuntu` and I use the `bash` shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid checking out each branch by staying on master and do:

```
git rebase master test_2
```

For the rest a quick bash command does the job

```
for branch in test_1 test_2 test_N
do
   git rebase master $branch
done
```

Comment: And If I have merge conflicts ?

Comment: at first conflict the command will stop and the next ones in the loop will do nothing (since there's a conflict). Solve your conflict, do a `git rebase --continue`, and rerun your loops with the remaining branches